# I will be dead, but not sooner or later?

Tags: existentialism, heidegger, properties

Are there properties, rather than the referents of terms, which can only be predicated of one thing?

> for those who attach metaphysical weight to the distinction between
> expressing (predicates) and referring (singular terms), questions
> about the meanings (now often known as the ‘semantic values’) of
> **singular terms like ‘honesty’ and ‘hunger’ and ‘being in love’** may be
> even more pressing. Since the chief task of singular terms is to refer
> to things, the semantic values of ‘honesty,’ ‘hunger’ and the like are
> presumably the things they refer to. But what could a word like
> ‘honesty’ refer to? If there are properties, it could refer to the
> property honesty

Heidegger seems adamant that no-one can die "my death" for me.

But can I predicate my death of me and only me? If not, how can Heidegger say he will die at noon? And if so, how could a philosopher argue that he will not?

Comment: Maybe "death" is not a property...

Comment: so it's an event? @MauroALLEGRANZA maybe i'm looking for something that can't be found. an unintuitive answer just from clarity?

Comment: Yes; IMO it is more reasonable to call it an [Event](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/events/).

Comment: Aside from the status of death, already Plato had [form-copies](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/plato-metaphysics/#8), such as the-large-in-Socrates, which were individualized to a particular. Alternatively, one can have generic properties the mode of possessing ("partaking") which is individualized.

Comment: sorry, i'm not a philosopher... what is a "form copy"? @Conifold seems very wrong to say when i'm dead i "partake" in death

Comment: SEP explains it under the link. That something dead partakes in deadness as a form is the usual platonic thesis. But "my death" as such is indeed not a property.